# Is it true that subadditivity together with absolute homogeneity implies that a function is nonnegative?

Tags: functions, inequality

Let $X$ denote some arbitrary linear space over $\mathbf{C}$ and suppose a function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ satisfies

$$f(x+y)\leq f(x)+f(y)\text{ and } f(ax) = |a|f(x)$$

for every pair $x,y\in X$ and $a\in \mathbf{C}$. The book I'm reading suggests that

$$|f(x-y)|\leq |f(x)|+|f(y)|$$

but this only follows from subadditivity if $f(x-y)\geq 0$. Now my question is if subadditivity and absolute homogeneity actually implies that $f\geq 0$. To that end I write the following basic proof: For every $x\in X$

$$f(x) = f(x+0)\leq f(x)+f(0)\Rightarrow f(0)\geq 0$$

and therefore

$$0 = f(0) = f(x-x)\leq f(x)+f(-x) = f(x)+f(x)=2f(x)\Rightarrow f(x)\geq 0.$$

Now what makes me confused is why the author then bothers with heavy use of the absolute value of $f$ (which he does) if the function so clearly is nonnegative? Is there something wrong with my assumption and proof that I don't directly see?

Comment: I was about to say that you were right and the book's usage of absolute values is indeed overkill, but I notice that, after defining the function over a real linear space, the definition of absolute homogeneity that you quoted involved complex scalars. So, I'm guessing that, in the context of this result in the book, the function $f$ is actually over a complex linear space and is complex-valued, hence the heavy use of moduli. But, I could be wrong.

Comment: You are absolutely right! It's supposed to be over complex scalars but the function is supposed to be real-valued. Therefore I don't see why this would affect my reasoning which says that $f$ must be positive

Comment: That really is weird. Subadditivity makes no sense over the complex numbers anyway.